# LinqtoSql Query In this scenario

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**Employee Table**
Primary Key:EmployeeID
[image]

**Machine Type Table**
Primary Key: MachineTypeID
[image]

**Machine Table:**
Primary Key: MachineID
Foreign Key: MachineTypeID
Foreign Key: EmployeeID

[image]

Database structure is described above now I want to query on Machine Table and show following results.
[image]

I want to know how to write LinqtoSql query to achieve above table.. is join works here. Kindly help me.

Comment: @SonerGönül stuck in logic.

Comment: @james the logic is the same in native `sql query`. BTW, have you heard about `navigation property`? it replaces partly the `Join` operation in tradition sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `DB/Object Context` named context, and also if you don't have navigations on entities(as *King King* says below your question), you can form a multiple-join query:

```
var result = 
from m  in context.Machine
join mt in context.MachineType on m.MachineTypeID equals mt.MachineTypeID
join e  in context.Employee    on m.EmployeeID    equals e.EmployeeId
select new { m.MachineID, mt.Type, e.EmployeeName, m.Price, m.Male, m.Year };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below will get you started:

This uses `navigation properties` instead of `joins`.

```
var result = context.Machines.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 3)
            .Select(v => new 
            { 
                v.MachineID, // from Machines table
                v.MachineTypes.MachineType, // from MachineTypes table
                v.Employees.EmployeeName, // from Employees table
                v.Price, // from Machines table
                v.Make, // from Machines table
                v.Year // from Machines table
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Machine
.Join
(
    MachineType,
    x=>x.MachineTypeID,
    x.MachineTypeID,
    (m,mt)=>new
    {
        m.MachineID,
        m.EmployeeID,
        m.Price,
        m.Make,
        m.Year,
        mt.Type
    }
)
.Join
(
    Employee,
    x=>x.EmployeeID,
    x=>x.EmployeeID,
    (m,e)=>new 
    {
        m.MachineID,
        MachineType = m.Type,
        Employee = m.EmployeeName,
        m.Price,
        m.Make,
        m.Year
    }
 );
```